# Why does NetworkX.convert.to_numpy_matrix() consumes away more memory than the source graph?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I'm using NetworkX (version 1.5) from a Python (2.6.5) application to convert a DiGraph object (72,000 nodes) to a Numpy (version 1.3) matrix. I don't have exact numbers or a code sample (I'm working on upgrading to newer versions to continue testing if this is an old issue) but loading my graph data into NetworkX.DiGraph uses an insignificant amount of ram on a VM with 46GB of memory.

When I NetworkX.convert.to_numpy_matrix(DiGraph.nodes()) memory consumption grows out of control. (exceeding 46GB I have allocated)

I have a similar problem with Numpy.eye(). It will grow way bigger than my estimate. For example, Numpy.eye(72000) will consume more than 46GB of ram.

The Numpy.eye() function which creates a matrix (2D array) and each entry in it should occupy an int’s worth of memory. (2 bytes) There’s some overhead, but I haven't tried to estimate it.

(Num of verts * num of verts) * 2 bytes
72,000 * 72,000 = 5184000000
5184000000 * 2 bytes = 10368000000 bytes or 10.3 GB

Again, I have 46GB of ram available. On a VM with less ram (8GB), Numpy.eye(72000) normally fails immediately with a "Memory Error" message. With my 46GB VM starts eating up memory uncontrolled.

Anyone have a suggestion or reason? I've seen clues that there have been Numpy memory usage issues, but they all generally address how the graph is generated, not why or how memory is allocated by Numpy.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's not clear to me if your question is actually about networkx or just about numpy.  If `numpy.eye` gives behavior you don't expect, then I think you should focus the question on that, since it means numpy is doing something weird independent of networkx.

Comment: numpy.eye(72000) generates floating-point numbers. floating point numbers are 8 bytes each.

Comment: Also i may suggest here the use of sparse matrix representation: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_scipy_sparse_matrix.html for your export. Should save you a lot of memory. But it has also drawbacks in terms of handling.

Comment: Thanks pv. I had an edit and response written up on my other PC, but it's internet is down right now. Yes, for some reason I concluded that the default dtype was int, not float, which it is.